# Write into a global array from another viewController

Tags: xcode4, nsarray, global-variables

I have an array in a viewController and I want to write into that array from another viewController, so I defined that array as global but I didn't manage to write into it!

**ViewController1.h**

```
extern NSArray *xArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *xArray;
```

**ViewController1.m**

```
@synthesize xArray;
NSArray *xArray;
xArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

**ViewController2.m**

```
#import "ViewController1.h"
NSArray *zArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",nil];
ViewController1.xArray = zArray;
```

I'm getting the following error:
*Property 'xArray' not found on object of type 'ViewController1'*

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, define the array in app delegate and use it in any class

**AppDelegate.h**

```
NSArray *xArray;
..
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *xArray;
..
@synthesize *xArray;
```

**ViewController1.m**

```
NSArray *tmpArray1;
AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
mainDelegate.xArray = tmpArray1;
```

**ViewController2.m**

```
NSArray *tmpArray2;
AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
mainDelegate.xArray = tmpArray2;
```